# How to Save Your Breakpoints so they are part of the Source Control committed Projects

Tags: xcode, git, version-control

Do you know how to backup your Xcode breakpoints using Source Control? Lately I have been using a lot of breakpoints to print out which part of the code fired. I had some trouble with a project and had to restore from my online Git repo and lost 85 breakpoints which really sucks. I had the same issue when I tried to share the project with another developer.

Here's a screen shot of what I mean about printing things with breakpoints.
[image]

The unchecked boxes here may be the answer but I don't know.
[image]

If you could please enlighten me that would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: never thought about sharing breakpoints, but I would assume that they are somewhere stored in the IDE project file..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was surprised to find that sharing breakpoints is actually a feature of the IDE. Here is some Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/sharing_a_breakpoint.html) on the matter.

From the article:

1. In the breakpoint navigator, Control-click the breakpoint.
2. From the shortcut menu, choose Share Breakpoint.